# How to use like clause query in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, sql-like, clause

I wanted to get a json format of the data when searching for the keyword so I use LIKE clause and query like this

```
"select * from employees where fname like ? or mname like ? or lname like ? or username like ? or id like ?", str, str, str, str, str
```

but I want to code it using rails. I have this code in my controller

```
def showemployees
  str = params[:str]
  render json: @employee = Employee.where(Employee.employees[:fname].matches("%#{str}%")) or
    (Employee.employees[:mname].matches("%#{str}%")) or
    (Employee.employees[:lname].matches("%#{str}%")) or
    (Employee.employees[:id].matches("%#{str}%"))
end
```

and this code in my config/routes.rb

```
get 'employees/showemployees'
root :to => 'employees#new'
resources :employees
post 'employees/update_info'
```

when i type this, http://localhost:3000/employees/showemployees?str=samplename, a json format of the record should appear yet I got this error message

```
undefined method `employees' for #<Class:0x8e38900>
app/controllers/employees_controller.rb:6:in `showemployees'
```

where line 6 has this code

```
render json: @employee = Employee.where(Employee.employees[:fname].matches("%#{str}%")) or
```

Comment: Please note that [`and`/`or` is *not* the same as `&&`/`||` in Ruby](http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/). Only the latter should be used when boolean logic is the intent. (Though this isn’t your problem here.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can chain where queries, but this `AND` each where query results

```
Employee.where('fname LIKE ?', "%#{str}%").where('lname LIKE ?', "%#{str}%").where('mname LIKE ?', "%#{str}%").where('username LIKE ?', "%#{str}%").where('id LIKE ?', "%#{str}%")
```

or to use `OR` clause

```
Employee.where('fname LIKE ? OR lname LIKE ? OR mname', "%#{str}%", "%#{str}%", "%#{str}%")
```

Comment: thanks, i got rid with the error but it returns null though my database has a record with the keyword entered

Comment: You can cut down on repetition with [named placeholders](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.1/active_record_querying.html#placeholder-conditions): `Employee.where('fname LIKE :q OR lname LIKE :q OR mname LIKE :q', q: "%#{str}%")`.

Comment: But unfortunately, the "%" and "_" characters in `str` won't be escaped! You need to escape these characters manually before using them in `"%#{str}%"`. You could do it like: `ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_like, str)`